# Translations for admin buttons are not used on the Tour page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, tour

There are a few strings on the site's tour page visible to moderators only. For some reason, translations from Traducir are not used here:

- For buttons below the main site description (<kbd>Save changes</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>):

> [image]

The same for the "Ask about..." and "However, you shouldn't ask about..." sections.

- For the button used to select a tour question (Edit question):

> [image]