# Unable to translate "Save changes", "Cancel" buttons on moderator election page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, election, localization

On every election page there's a possibility to edit a notice of election (if you're a site moderator). When you started an edit there are two buttons "Save changes" and "Cancel":

> [image]

These buttons for some reason are not used by translation engine.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a similar issue to this one you reported earlier: [Translations for admin buttons are not used on the Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393738/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast probably yes. There are [3 reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22save+changes%22+user%3A339911) related to "save changes" posted by me.